# Lost references with “Compile PDF” for a Sweave vignette in RStudio

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio, sweave, vignette

“Compile PDF” in RStudio 0.99.902 with R 3.3.0 cannot find references included in the “sos” Sweave vignette that's been part of the “sos” package on CRAN since 2009.  It produces “sos.pdf”, which reads mostly OK, except that the inline references are replace by something like “?”.

For example, an entry “\citet[pp. 282-283]{JC09}” that previously translated into “Chambers (2009, pp. 282-283)” now displays as “?, pp. 282-283”.  The “\bibitem[Chambers(2009)]{JC09}” entry is still at the end of the file and prints with the Bibliography, but “Compile PDF” in RStudio cannot find it make the proper substitution for “\citet[pp. 282-283]{JC09}”.

Any suggestion on how to fix this?
Thanks,

Comment: you'll have better luck on this site if you always provide a minimal self-contained reproducible example that others can copy, paste, and run.

Comment: It worked for me in OSX.  It would likely give the symptoms you describe if you didn't have write permission to write the .bbl file, or something else caused that to fail.

Comment: Forgot to mention:  you need to uncomment one of the \usepackage{Sweave} lines.